# Thread class Instance after completion of run method

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I am trying to learn multi-threading in Java. We use two methods to create a thread, the first is by extending the Thread class and the second method is by implementing the Runnable interface.

In below example, I have created a thread by implementing Runnable interface.

```java
class ThreadExample implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("run method is called by thread named " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

        System.out.println("run method is ending for thread named " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

    }

}

public class TestInterruptingThread2 extends Thread {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ThreadExample threadExample = new ThreadExample();
        Thread thread = new Thread(threadExample);
        thread.start();

    }
}
```

output is -

```java
run method is called by thread named Thread-0
run method is ending for thread named Thread-0
```

As shown in above example, to create a thread of ThreadExample class we first create its object and then pass it to **constructor of Thread** class.

My question is that after the completion of run() method, what happens to the instance of **Thread** class to which object of **ThreadExample** class object is passed. Does it become eligible for garbage collection?

And also how creating thread by implementing Runnable interface is more memory efficient than by extending Thread class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does it become eligible for garbage collection?

Yes.  When a `Thread` instance has terminated and once all other references to the object are lost, it will become unreachable and will be a candidate for garbage collection.

Note that the thread's stack will typically be reclaimed *before* the garbage collector runs.  (It is triggered by the thread's termination.)

---

> How creating thread by implementing `Runnable` interface is more memory efficient than by extending `Thread` class?

That is not really the issue.

The *performance related* reason for not extending `Thread` derives from the fact that creating and starting a `Thread` or class derived from `Thread` is expensive.  (On some platforms, it can take in the order of a millisecond!)  So you want to avoid repeatedly creating new `Thread` objects.

The standard way to do this to use either a thread pool or an `ExecutorService`.  These work by encapsulating a task as a `Runnable` (or a `Callable`) and passing that to a long running worker / pool thread.  Such a thread will typically process a large number of these tasks (one at a time) over its lifetime so that the cost of thread creation is *amortized* over a number of tasks ... and becomes insignificant.

How does this relate to `new Thread(Runnable)` versus `extends Thread`?

Well in the former case, you have already encapsulated your task as a `Runnable`, so converting your applications to use a thread pool / executor is relatively straightforward.  By contrast, if you extended `Thread` you have to change significantly more code.

Now ... you could implement a thread pool for your custom thread class.  However a typical thread pool implementation has some complicated logic and thread-safety concerns, so that is a bad idea.

---

There are other reasons why extending `Thread` is a bad idea too.  But you were only asking about performance related reasons.

Comment: Hi @Stephen, Thanks for your response. Could you please tell when instance of Thread class thread that I have created will be eligible for garbage collection? After completion of run() method if I set thread = null ?

Comment: Yes.  Provided you haven't kept a reference to the `Thread` instance anywhere else.